# Is there a way I can send a mongodb collection to an ejs file as an ordered list?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, ejs

I can only get as far as showing the collection as a json object in its own route, but I want to get the collection to show in a list under my index.ejs file (I'm new to ejs and MongoDB).

Here's the code where I can see the json object in localhost:3000/signups:

```
  app.get("/signups", (req, res) => {
    volunteer.find({}, function(err, foundData) {
    if(err){
     res.send('Oops, something went wrong!');
     next();
    }
    res.json(foundData);
  });
 });
```

Here's my index.ejs:

```
<body>
 <h1>Hi <%= name %></h1>

 <h1>Volunteers:</h1>

 <!--I want to list all volunteers from the mongodb collection-->
 <div id="volunteer-table"></div>
 </body>
```

Here's what I see when i use db.volunteers.find().pretty() in a mongo shell:

```
[{"_id":"5dc0e9540d7f0781882910e1","firstName":"michael","lastName":"Scott","email":"ms@dunder.com","__v":0},]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this. One way would be to edit your index route to grab the volunteers and send them directly to the EJS template. Something like this should do the trick (untested, so may require edits):

```js
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    volunteer.find({}, function(err, foundData) {
        if (err){
            res.send('Oops, something went wrong!');
            next();
            return;
        }

        // pass volunteers directly into page
        res.render('index', {
            name: 'My Page',
            volunteers: foundData,
        });
    });
});
```

**index.ejs:**

```
<table>
<% for (var i=0; i < volunteers.length; i++) { %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= volunteers[i].firstName %></td>
     <td><%= volunteers[i].lastName %></td>
     <td><%= volunteers[i].email %></td>
   </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

---

### The Preferred Method

Another way would be to keep your index route the same, and request the volunteer endpoint from the front-end. You wouldn't even need to use EJS. In my opinion, this is the better option, because it decouples the front-end rendering from the back-end (making your application more flexible).

For example:

**index.ejs:**

```html
<body>
    <h1>Hi <%= name %></h1>

    <h1>Volunteers:</h1>

    <div id="volunteer-table"></div>
</body>

<script>
    async function main() {
        // fetch volunteers
        const response = await fetch('/signups');
        const volunteers = await response.json();

        // build an HTML table
        let volunteerTable = "<table>";
        for (const volunteer of volunteers) {
            volunteerTable += `
            <tr>
                <td>${volunteer.firstName}</td>
                <td>${volunteer.lastName}</td>
                <td>${volunteer.email}</td>
            </tr>
            `;
        }
        volunteerTable += "</table>";

        // insert the table into the view
        document.getElementById('volunteer-table').innerHTML = volunteerTable;
    }

    main();
</script>
```

(Again, untested, so the above code may require some slight edits.)

This approach would work even better with a front-end framework like React or Vue.

Comment: @burnsie Glad I could help!